# How can I align some elements in the mobile version of my website?

Tags: html, css

i would like to know how is possibile to align some elemtents with Bootstrap, in order to have a more clean look for the mobile/ipad version of my website. The "01.1 Fake News" and the paragraph under it should have a margin-left that is the same of the images under it, same for "01.2 Wittgenstein Posters". I'm adding an image of the website in order for you to see it. [image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo+Black&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="icone/favicon_32x32.png" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Giulia Giordano
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top mt-lg-4 mt-sm-0 mt-md-4 mt-xl-4">
            <a class="navbar-brand ml-4" href="index.html">
                <img src="img/logo.png" width=100% alt="" loading="lazy">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item mr-4">
                        <a href="index.html" class="nav-link text-dark">home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mr-4">
                        <div class="dropdown show">
                            <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                progetti
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">

                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="graphicdesign.html">01. Graphic Design</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="videografica.html">02. Videografica</a>
                            </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mr-4">
                        <a href="chisono.html" class="nav-link text-dark ">chi sono?</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item mr-1">
                        <a href="contattami.html" class="nav-link text-dark">contattami</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block fullScreen">
                <img src="img/gd_graphicdesigngenerale.gif" class="fullScreen" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md d-flex align-items-center vertical-container justify-content-center fullScreen">
                <div class="row mt-5">
                    <div class="offset-2 mt-15"></div>
                    <h2 class=" text-purple mt-5 mt-15">01</h2>
                    <div class="offset-1"></div>
                    <h2 class=" text-purple ml-3 mt-5 ">graphic <br>design</h2>
                    <div class="d-flex offset-3 vertical-container align-items-center">
                        <p class="col-9 display-5 mt-5 ml-3 mb-5 mr-6">Qui puoi trovare una selezione dei miei progetti di graphic design. La monografia di Armin Hofmann, grafico pioniero dello Swiss Design, e i cinque poster di tipografia espressiva realizzati per gli aforismi di Ludwig Wittgenstein. Tutti questi lavori sono stati eseguiti all'Accademia di Belle Arti di Palermo.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="offset-4">

                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row purple-white-section2" >
            <div class="col-lg">
                <div class="d-flex vertical-container align-items-center">
                    <div class="justify-content-start col-sm-8">
                        <h3 class="mt-5 mb-4">01.1</h3>
                        <h3 class="font-weight-lighter mt-5">How to Fight <br> Fake News</h3>
                        <p class=" display-5 mt-5">È possibile sconfiggere le fake
                            news? Perché è così difficile
                            riconoscerle e scovarle? Qual è
                            stata la prima bufala della storia? Alcune delle domande a cui questo
                            manuale risponde, una guida per
                            sconfiggere le notizie false.</p>
                        <a href="fakenews.html"><img src="scopridipiu/scopridipiu.png" alt="" class="mt-5"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg d-flex vertical-container align-items-center"><img
                    src="photoshop/graphicdesign_generale/img/fakenews_generale_2.jpg" class="img-fluid p-4 mt-4" alt=""><img
                    src="photoshop/graphicdesign_generale/img/fakenews_generale_3.jpg" class="img-fluid p-4 mt-4" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg d-flex align-items-center">
                <img src="photoshop/graphicdesign_generale/img/black.png" width="50%" alt="">
                <img src="photoshop/graphicdesign_generale/img/viola.png" class="mt-5" width="50%" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg order-first order-lg-0 d-flex vertical-container align-items-center mt-4">
                <div class="justify-content-start col-sm-8">
                    <h3 class="mt-5 mb-4 text-purple">01.2</h3>
                    <h3 class="font-weight-lighter mt-5">Wittengstein <br> poster</h3>
                    <p class="display-5 mt-5">Esercizio di tipografia espressiva.
                        Quattro aforismi del famoso
                        filosofo Ludwig Wittengstein
                        spiegati attraverso la tipografia e
                        il colore. Lavoro realizzto durante
                        il mo primo anno all’Accademia di
                        Belle Arti di Palermo.
                    </p>
                    <a href="wittengstein.html"><img src="scopridipiu/scopridipiu_viola.png" alt="" class="mt-5"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <div class="row p-4">
                <div class="mr-auto mt-2 ml-4 text-purple">
                    <h6>© All rights reserved to Giulia Giordano
                    </h6>
                </div>
                <div class="ml-auto mr-4">
                    <a class="mr-3" href="https://www.instagram.com/grappaiulia/">
                        <img alt="instagram" src="icone/instagram.png" title="instagram" width="20"></a>
                    <a class="mr-3"
                        href="https://www.behance.net/giulia_giordano?tracking_source=search_users_recommended%7Cgiulia%20giordano"
                        target="_blank">
                        <img alt="behance" src="icone/behance.png" title="behance" width="20">
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your question here. I'm sorry, but I find it a bit difficult to understand as you've put so many things. Can you try to be very specific?

Answer (score 1):

You have the main title (graphic design) and the sub titles (01 and 02) within different structure and styling classes. Since these different tags and classes have different css styles, you will see - well- a difference.

Also, it's very much possible you are stacking margin styles for your sub titles. Meaning that your subs are experiences margin for themselves, but also the margin from their parent elements.

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation, I'm a beginner and I was a bit confused!